Tibetan terminology
What is the Tibetan term for describing the realm containing all of one individual mindstream's karma? I think it starts with the letter A. Thank you 

"the fundamental store-house consciousness (ālāyavijñāna).."?

That's it! Merci ❤️

@blue_ego Please write it as an answer

or maybe u meant "Citta-saṃtāna (Sanskrit), literally "the stream of mind""..

The alayavijnana is the store-house of the stream of mind is it not?
